# After creating file using java, there were no values in it

Tags: java, file

I  have created file using java, with following code

```
String Filecontent= "hei";
```

creating file

```
PrintWriter writer=new PrintWriter("D://balanworkspace//Coretest//Corejavatest//src//intvquestest//mydet3_8.txt","UTF-8");
```

printing the string

```
System.out.println(Filecontent);
```

writing to file

```
writer.println(Filecontent);
```

when I opened the file, there is no values.  Why is it so?

Comment: The double slashes `//` are hot necessary. Doubling is only necessary for backslashes `\\\`.

Answer (score 5):

You need to close the `PrintWriter` by doing this:

```
writer.close();
```

Comment: Alber Xiao thanks for answers got code worked thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the complete path of your file exists... If not, create a `File` and use `mkdirs` method to create it. After that, write with your `PrintWriter`

```
 File f = null;
     f = new File("yourpath"); 
 Boolean  bool = f.mkdirs();
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to flush the stream, for the values to appear in the file.

```
writer.flush()
```

Closing the stream will invoke the same,

```
writer.close()
```

If you don't want to use flush and close, you could pass in an argument  "true" to the constructor of PrintWriter which will cause the output to be flushed each time println() is invoked.

```
PrintWriter(Writer out, boolean autoFlush)
```